# Mouse position does not refresh in ubuntu gnome 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mouse, ubuntu-gnome

I recently started using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04. When I move the mouse around the screen, the screen does not refresh. Mouse keeps responding but its images randomly stick to parts of the screen along the path traversed by the cursor.

This question has also been asked here

[Mouse Lag in ubuntu Gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/808000/mouse-lag-in-ubuntu-gnome)

But none has responded yet. How can I ensure that the screen is properly refreshed? Or if something else is causing the problem, please help me diagnose it.