# Ubuntu 19.04 lags and high CPU usage

Tags: cpu-load, 19.04

CPU usage sometimes rises to 100% without anything running in the background. Also the animations lag.

My rig:

Processor : Intel(R)Core(TN)i3-4150CPU@3.50Ghz

Installed RAM: 4.00GB

Graphics : Nvidia GTX 610

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: if you take a look in prosseses what do you see there,anything using lot of prossesor time.top right of your screen do show a stop sign what do this say when you click on it.

Comment: My hunch is that the animations (even subtle ones like hovering over windows that cause scrollbars to appear or hide, or menu items to highlight) may be the occasional cause of your problem. It was for me and [here's my fix](https://askubuntu.com/a/1144922/1698).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and partial fix was to open Settings => Search, then use main switch on the top to disable everything.
System became a bit faster but still very laggy compared to 18.04 and 18.10.