# Ubuntu 19.04 Gnome Freezes

Tags: gnome, 19.04

My Ubuntu 19.04 on vmware with vmware tools installed and 3d acceleration enabled freezes the gnome UI from time to time. It seems to be reproducable when starting certain applications from the app store, however, also happens without anything special done. Fun fact: the mouse still moves and I can see the cursor / pointer react on the view (like hower buttons or textfields). Also I blindly can open the terminal via shortcut and reboot the machine. This said I had situations where it recovered or changed the image after minutes and freezed again. However, mostly once frozen it's frozen.

ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions

Results in No such file or directoy. Assuming that no extensions are installed.

I am new to ubuntu desktop and a windows pro.  Maybe pointing at the right log might help me already.

Comment: Do you have any GNOME extensions installed? Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: @heynnema Done. No extensions

Comment: You could file a bug report...

Comment: `/var/log/syslog*`

Answer (score 1):

The VM emulates a graphics chipset. That chipset driver likely can't handle the animations very well without CPU climb, and, thus, mouse lag. I have VirtualBox and experience the same problem on MacOS with Lubuntu 19.04.

Sometimes it's hard to notice that it's the animations doing this. In my case, I was using Pluma and moving my mouse around, and it would occasionally stick. At first, I thought it had to do with VM hypervirtualization, mouse polling rate, or screen refresh rate. That's when I realized that it was animating a scrollbar on and off as I moved the mouse in Pluma. It would also occasionally lag when hovering over Pluma toolbar menus and other visual elements. Once it cached, it sped it up slightly, but then would return a few seconds later if I repeated tasks.

[This was my bandaid fix.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1144922/1698)

Probably a better solution would be for someone to fix the chipset driver to work better with these animations, or change the animation API so that it works better with VM chipsets. However, turning off most of the animations seems to really help me for now. Besides, I use my Linux VM to get work done -- not entertain myself with animations.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. The problem was solved when I changed the nvidia 418 driver to the noveau driver. I hope they'll fix this bug soon because I need de proprietary driver to play some games. I have a Geforce 960m.