# Cursor lag jumping between touchpad and wireless mouse in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, mouse, touchpad

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 on a HP Laptop 15s-eq0xxx laptop, with an AMD Ryzen 7 3700u processor, and 16 GB of memory.

Recently the touchpad showed lag and sometimes became fully unresponsive at the same time as the fan was speeding up. The only solution to this was resetting the window environment with Alt+F2 and running 'r' as a command, but the lag would come back. Sometimes I rebooted the laptop while the touchpad was unresponsive, and on reboot it presented a message about 'clearing orphaned inode'.

After running the commands in [Mouse Lag in ubuntu Gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/808000/mouse-lag-in-ubuntu-gnome), the problem became rarer, but the lag still sometimes happen.

I've now noticed that it also happens when I use a wireless mouse, under the same situations. The strangest part is that whenever the lag happens to the mouse the touchpad works well, and when it happens to the touchpad, the mouse is working. It seems to happen to whichever device I happen to be using, as if it is being throttled to maintain performance. However, it happens when simply playing a video or using a browser.

Any advice on what I can do to address this, or diagnostics I could run to figure out the problem? I would share a video of the lag, but the Ubuntu screencast does not record the cursor (even with that option selected).